# Adding hyperlinks in a Google Form

Tags: google-forms

How can I add hyperlinks in Google Form?

Answer (score 13):

Here's how.

Add the host (eg. www) and domain name (eg. google.com) without the protocol or an html anchor. In other words:

**Works**

```
www.google.com
gmail.google.com
```

**Will not work**

```
google.com
http://google.com
<a href="http://www.google.com/">google<a/>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Currently, the only place you can put hyperlinks in a Google form is in the second box from the top** (aka the description box). Anywhere else and the URL wont be clickable.

*To add a URL to the discription box simply type the URL with or without the `http://`. You **dont** need to add any HTML markup. eg Typing `google.com` will result in [google.com](http://google.com)*

[image: Edit Form View]

Its a feature that has been requested before but so far Google hasn't added it yet. All we can do is wait in anticipation!

Comment: but how can i add it there? i cant see any option which would allow me to add a clickable URL - or do i need to use some HTML code? because it doesnt seem to be working for me... PLEASE HELP!

Comment: My form is here - [http://www.mkti.cz/konference/](http://www.mkti.cz/konference/) and what i need to do, is to add to the very last part of the form this hyperlink - [http://www.mkti.cz/konference/obchodni_podminky](http://www.mkti.cz/konference/obchodni_podminky) (its blind right now) Any chance you could help me please?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You just need to type the address **without** any HTML code and google will translate it into a clickable URL. But this ONLY works in the description box 2nd from the top. Clickable URLs dont work anywhere else in a google form

Comment: Links can now be added in any type of question or Answers from Checklist, Multiple Choice, Grid, Section Breaker. You indeed should not put html anchor or protocol.

Comment: @OrangeBox This answer should be updated to include the fact that this is now acceptable.

Comment: You can also add a link on the Confirmation page, per the top answer above (e.g.,   www.google.com  works , http://www.google.com does not, and do NOT include html/anchor tags.

Answer (score 1):

Oscar is right. You can also add a hyperlink in the confirmation page and it will become clickable.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

You can also add hyperlinks in the confirmation page - again, leave the 'http://' off your link

Comment: Can you share a screenshot with us?

Answer (score -1):

Hyperlinks can be added to all parts of the Google form, even in section and page headers, as well as multiple choice questions. Haven't check with list, grids and scales though.

see [sample form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1v2QBKqdmch-wT8PhtJM0KL17PObKwsQrhqfwEtmTnf4/viewform)

Comment: The question was **how** to do that.