# Is there a way to put an aliased hyperlink in the confirmation message of Google Forms?

Tags: google-forms, links

I'd like the message to look like:

> thanks for your answer, please click `here`

while the word "here" is clickable and directs to a URL.

I've tried wrapping the hyperlink with quotes, and these while customizing the confirmation message, but they are displayed exactly like the code itself, except for the hyperlink which is clickable:

```
[alias](hyperlink)

<a href=hyperlink>alias</a>

[[hyperlink|alias]]

HYPERLINK(hyperlink, alias)

=HYPERLINK(hyperlink, alias)
```

I've found nothing in the API documentation for [setConfirmationMessage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setConfirmationMessage(String)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of Dec 2017, Google product development has yet to add support for any aliased links in the Confirmation Message displayed upon completing a Google Form.
Refer to these dated forum discussions that indicate the lack of such support:

- [Adding hyperlinks in a Google Form](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29154/adding-hyperlinks-in-a-google-form)
- https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/3pr_SStcqEQ
- https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/_tFH6SSN6Nk;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/authorid$3AAPn2wQf6-liCQ5P4ll4jWQ3ZsBz_4jIji3FNetyUVOU7bhln9oErnFqPU4kCCWYACACeaJpjlGo1%7Csort:date%7Cspell:false

However, if you decide to setup and send an email notification, there are several free add-ons for Google Form, where you can definitely alias hyperlinks and customize even further.

Alternatively, if you elect to share all responses with the recipient, you may be able to apply your confirmation message in the google sheet, and embed an aliased link within that. (To do so, concatenate the text with the hyperlink() function)